Is there a context where the sentence "She ran in ten minutes." is correct?
the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 668:

(1) She ran in ten minutes. — incorrect

I'm curious about whether there is a context where (1) is correct. For example:
Mother: Where are you going?
Daughter: Today is a competition. I'm going to support my friend Ann. She will run a distance of three kilometers.
After several hours the daughter comes home.
Mother: How did it go?
Daughter: (1) She ran in ten minutes.
Is (1) correct in the context I came up with?

Where you say "She will run a distance  of three kilometers" a native-speaker would probably say "She's running a 3K".  And thus the final remark would be "She ran it in ten minutes".  Any mention of a race earlier in the conversation is likely to result in the daughter's remark using the pronoun "it", not "She ran in ten minutes", which is ungrammatical.  But "She finished in ten minutes" is possible.

The direct object invokes the verb ran's telicity.

Again, it's one of these edge cases that interests the grammarian. It's not incorrect in the way that "Ran in minutes ten she."  would be but still not quite right.  The main reason is that the natural meaning (indicating a duration) would be expressed with "for" not "in".
But if the transitive form of the verb is used, or the verb has a PP that gives a destination or location, then "in" becomes possible  (and "for five minutes" would be incorrect).

She ran the race in five minutes.


She ran to the shops in five minutes.

in your situation

She ran it in ten minutes.

There isn't really much "logic" about the choice of prepositions, many are just colocations with particular senses of particular verbs.
